# ActionScript 3, Creating Instances of Library's Movie Clip for appropriate Scene

Tags: actionscript-3, class, instance, public

Hello stackoverflow gurus.
I am new to AS3, and sorry if my questions would be somewhat naive, but...

I have Movie Clip progress_mc in my Library.
I also have 3 Scenes, with 50-framed Motion Tweens.
And some control buttons to play appropriate Scene.

**Question 1**. How can I create an Instance of progress_mc using DocumentClass?
I've already tried somewhat like this in that class:

```
public class ProgressMc extends MovieClip  
{  
  public function addInstance():void  
{    
  var progress_mc:MovieClip = new MovieClip();  
  this.addChild(progress_mc);  
}  
}
```

Then I just put

```
addInstance();
```

for the 1 frame of Scene1.
But it doesn't work. No Instance appears.

Maybe such approach is wrong... Show me some correct, please.

**Question 2.** And how to create an Instance for appropriate Scene?
Should I put the call of public function at every 1-st frame of each scene?
Or there is some correct decision?

**EDIT-1:**
OK, I found the answer.
Step1. As mitim described.
Step2. Using this code at timeline:

```
var p1:progress_mc = new progress_mc();

p1.name = "p1";
p1.x = 50;
p1.y = 50;

addChild(p1);
```

However, It is still not evident about

```
.Scene
```

possibilities.  But wrapping all the Scene in one Movie Clip is a variant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(I am making an assumption you're using the flash IDE)

For question 1, you need to set the class linkage name of "progress_mc" movieclip in your library. Go to it's properties in the library and check "export for actionscript" and set it's class name. Then instead of going:

```
new MovieClip()
```

which does make a new empty Movieclip object, you'd go

```
new MyClassName()
```

to create a new instance of that library clip. Then you can add it to stage like you're currently doing so.

For question 2, I'm not exactly sure what is in your scene...but if it is just frame animation, scenes could be wrapped in movieclips and treated the same.

Comment: Thanks for reply, mitim. I've created class for this mc: package
{
 import flash.display.MovieClip;
 
 
 public class progress_mc extends MovieClip  
 {  
    public function addInstance():void  
  {    
    var progress_mc:MovieClip = new progress_mc();  
    this.addChild(progress_mc);  
  }
  
 }
 
 
}   But there is something wrong with timeline code **addInstance()**; I've aslo used this.addInstance();but there is error:TypeError: Error #1006: addInstance is not a function.
 at Objects1_fla::MainTimeline/Objects1_fla::frame1()<pre>